# Flex display issue -- trying to have two columns where row height is independent of each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to display two columns where the rows maintain independent heights for the displayable content. I'm using flex containers for this.

Just to highlight this again: I'm trying to maintain independent row height so the effect is masonry. To see this, run the code snippet below and enlarge your screen to see this masonry effect.

My solution doesn't maintain the order of the elements when the page is observed on a mobile device.

Example on a large screen of what I'd like:

```
Col1.    |   Col2.
Item 1       Item 2
Item 3       Item 4
Item 5
```

Example of the same content on a mobile device:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
```

Here's my solution that while appearing to work, doesn't maintain order. Is there a better way to do this? Or is there an easy fix?

The only other solution I've come up with is to have two display blocks and hide/show the appropriate ones per media query. This feels hacky though and there must be a better alternative.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container-row {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.container-column {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 45%;
}

.item {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}


/* default */

@media screen and (min-width:0px) {
  html {
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  .container-row {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .container-column {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}


/* large */

@media screen and (min-width:992px) {
  html {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .container-row {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .container-column {
    flex-basis: 45%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-row">

    <div class="container-column">
      <div style="order:1" class="item">
        <a href="#">1 Item</a>
      </div>

      <div style="order:3" class="item">
        <a href="#">3 Item</a>
      </div>

      <div style="order:5" class="item">
        <a href="#">5 Item</a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-column">
      <div style="order:2" class="item">
        <a href="#">2 Item</a>
      </div>

      <div style="order:4" class="item">
        <a href="#">4 Item; this is really long text so that this line appears as multi-line; disregard this text entirely; this is really long text so that the line appears as multi-line</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

It is a 2-dimensional layout, I would suggest using Grid Layout, as it is very efficient in managing 2 Dimensional Layout, It makes HTML structure simpler and CSS easier to understand I have created a demo on CodeSandbox, please have a view of that and let me know if you have any query
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-mayer-l4y90d?file=/index.html)

Some resources for Grid Layout

- [Css grid from CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
- [CSS grid from MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Comment: Thank you Bhavesh for your support, but this doesn't address the masonry aspect of my problem. You can clearly see this when you enlarge the screen and the grid becomes two columns.

Comment: I solved the above issue using grid, flex, and inline-blocks, but all of them use rows that maintain heights across the row. I therefore need to use columns so rows are independent of each other. The problem is then the order.

Comment: I would recommend to guys who did negative voting to explain why they did, I have provided approx 30 min to the answers, It demotivates when your answer gets the negative vote, and the one who does the negative vote does not specify the reason.

Comment: @Gary can you provide the solution that is working using grid, I can might help in that

Comment: Thank you Bhavesh, but it's the same behavior as w/Flex. I don't think this can be done but w/two DOM variations (e.g., two divs) on the page where I hide one and show the other based on desktop/tablet/mobile.